# Random guessing game (integer) - bug when entering string

Tags: c, string, random, numbers

I am making a typical guessing game to learn C for the first time in my life and I noticed a bug. If you enter an integer you will get `Guess a higher value` or `Guess a lower value` and that works just fine. But if you put in a string, it goes insane and prints out a lot of strings saying `Guess a higher value`.

1. What I am trying to do now is to make a check for if the user enters a string, it will say to the user something like `Enter a number, not text`. How do I do this?
2. Is there anything you see that I can improve in this code?

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <time.h>
   int main () {

       int secret, answer;

       srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

       secret = rand() % 10 + 1;

       do {
           printf ("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
           scanf ("%d",&answer);
           if (secret<answer) puts ("Guess a higher value");
           else if (secret>answer) puts ("Guess a lower value");
       } while (secret!=answer);

       puts ("Congratz!");
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Changed the tag accordingly (C not C++).

Comment: Oh, it is? Well... Isn't the example very simple? Isn't C and C++ pretty much a like? This example is not that diffrent in the two languages.

Comment: @user1431627: It can be surprising because most C can be compiled as C++ and work similarly (though C++ is not a strict superset). But you did not use any feature of C++ here, pure C code. (and I would dare say, pure C89 code)

Comment: Thank you! I will compile it in C, then. If I were to use C++, `printf()` would be `cout << <<`? What would you recomend me to use?

Answer (score 1):

You are ignoring the return value of `scanf`, which will tell you if the conversion went well or not. `scanf` will return the number of items assigned, so if it returns 1 you know that `answer` was assigned to a number. If it returns 0, you know that something went wrong.

Comment: It returns 0 when I stop my application.

Comment: Then you know that the user did not enter a vaild number. Print an error message and prompt the user again.

Answer (score 0):

> What I am trying to do now is to make a check for if the user enters a
>   string, it will say to the user something like Enter a number, not
>   text. How do I do this?

`scanf` does formatted input. You may also want to check out advanced formatting specifiers in `scanf` -- such as ignoring parts of the input, specifying buffer size for reading in strings, specifying only a particular set of characters that you want to read etc. If you want to verify input, you are probably best of reading a line from the console using `fgets` and then parsing the line.

> Is there anything you see that I can improve in this code?

You may want to improve your random number generation algorithm. Read the C FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of `scanf` . It will return the number of items successfully matched and assigned. In this case if you enter a string then it will not be matched and assigned, but the string stays in the input buffer, and the `scanf` tries to read it in each iteration and fails, and thus the problem arises.

You may change the code to:

```
int main () {

    int secret, answer;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    secret = rand() % 10 + 1;

    do {
        printf ("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
        if (scanf ("%d",&answer) != 1)
        {
         printf ("\nPlease enter an integer\n\n");
         scanf ("%*s");
         continue;
        }
        if (secret<answer) puts ("Guess a higher value");
        else if (secret>answer) puts ("Guess a lower value");
    } while (secret!=answer);

    puts ("Congratz!");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that inside the `if` the line `scanf ("%*s");` is done. In the `%*s` the `*` is the input supression indicator, this tells that a string (stands for `%s`) will be read but the `*` tells that although the string will be read from the input, it will be discarded. This is being done to simply discard the previously entered string which is not read by the `scanf ("%d",&answer)` . In case you do not discard the string in the buffer, it will remain, and each iteration the `scanf ("%d",&answer)` will fail to match any integer, as it will encounter the leftover string in the input buffer.

On the other hand you may read a string and convert the string to an integer.

Like as below:

```
int main () {

    int secret, answer;
    char buff[128];

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    secret = rand() % 10 + 1;
    do {
        printf ("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
        scanf ("%s",buff);
        if ((answer = atoi (buff)) == 0)
        {
          printf ("\nPlease enter an integer\n\n");
          continue;
        }
        if (secret<answer) puts ("Guess a higher value");
        else if (secret>answer) puts ("Guess a lower value");
    } while (secret!=answer);

    puts ("Congratz!");
    return 0;
}
```

`atoi ()` will convert a string to an integer (in 10 base). If the characters which comprises the integer does not contain valid digits, it will return `0`. Checking for it we can detect if the user entered correctly. Also because your application needs to enter an integer within 1 and 10 therefore 0 is not included, therefore it is okay to take 0 as an invalid. To get better control on detecting an invalid integer format, and the location of the error in the string use `strtol ()`

Comment: When I use your code, the program will not work properly. It always says `Guess a lower value, but there is no value from 1 to 10. I have tried all possible numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you are facing. which code the above one or the below ?

Comment: The first code. EDIT: Checked now: the one below dose not work either. It just say I need a lower number.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make a function to check if the input is numeric. Like:

```
int isNumeric( char *str){
   while(*str)
   {
     if (!isdigit(*str))
         return 0;
     str++;
   }
   return 1;
}

int main(){
   char guess[3];
   int iGuess;
   do {
      printf("Guess a number between 1 and 10");
      gets(guess);
      if (!isNumeric(guess)){
        printf("Invalid input");
        continue;
      }
      iGuess = atoi(guess);
     if (iGuess<secret)
           printf("Higher");
     else if (iGuess>secret)
           printf("Lower");
   } while (secret!=iGuess);
   printf("Congrats");
   return 0;
}
```

You need to include ctype.h  and string.h